# why do we need a database driver?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Who provides this database driver ? If I'm using an oracle database, does oracle provide this driver. Why do we need a database driver manager and who provides this ? Can you explain this for the Java environment. 
EDIT: I'm using a hibernate layer in between which makes my code independent of the database I'm using, so what does the database driver do in this case ? Does it intercept calls from hibernate translate into something oracle will understand ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every database vendor provides their own database drivers.

Why?

Because database is also a software and there should be a way your program need to communicate with database.